# Is it save to change the cursor position of an ADODB.Recordset that is attached to a ListBox?

Tags: ms-access, ado

I need to do some tasks with a Recordset that is attached to a ListBox. For ex. looping over to search for records.

Is there any problem doing so?

---

**Edit**
 Well better I explain what I trying to do:

The Recordset contains a List of records that is displayed in a ListBox. The user can navigate and select one entry. The selected record will queried with full detail and then displayed in the form.

The user can change the filter and reload the Recordset and as result the ListBox conatins different Records.

Now I want to loop over the new loaded recordset to find out if the currently in the form displayed record is still in the Listbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over bound recordsets, you generally should just clone them:

```
Dim rsClone As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsClone = MyListbox.Recordset.Clone(adLockReadOnly)
With rsClone
    If Not .EOF And .BOF Then .MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF
        'Etc
```

I've never really encountered errors on a recordset that just was being used as a row source, though, but I haven't really tried since I tend to always use a clone.

Comment: Should I also clone, if I use Find, which will change the cursor pos?

Comment: Generally, I recommend cloning for every operation that will change the cursor. You can just use `.Filter`, though, that won't change the cursor.

Comment: In this case, I can filter with the pkey and test for RecordCount. Thx.